# Cannot install JavaFX SDK despite having current JDK

Tags: windows-7, java, jdk

I want to install the JavaFX SDK and it keeps telling that it requires the current JDK to be installed, which I definitely have. Why doesn't the installation recognize my JDK? How can I fix this so I can install the JavaFX SDK?

Comment: More information about the operating system being used is required to answer this question.

Comment: Sorry for missing that. I'm working on Windows 7 Prof. x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See settings in `deployment.properties` file

```
type "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" | find /I "\\Java\\"
```

or

```
type "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" | find /I ".path=" | find /I "deployment.javaws."
```

serach JVM JDK path:

```
type "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" | find /I "jdk"
```

search JVM JDK cpl console x64:

```
dir /B /S %ProgramFiles%\Java\*javacpl.exe | find /I "jdk"
```

search JVM JDK cpl console x86:

```
dir /B /S %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\*javacpl.exe | find /I "jdk"
```

run JVM JDK cpl console:

```
C:\App64\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\javacpl.exe
```

jump to `deployment.properties` file

```
explorer "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment"
```

see registry Java addon:

```
powershell gci 'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{CAFEEFAC*'-rec^| gp ^| select '(default)', PSPath ^| ft -auto
```

del `java` and `javaw` at `%windir%` and `%windir%\system32`

```
del /Q /F %windir%\system32\java.exe
del /Q /F %windir%\java.exe

del /Q /F %windir%\system32\javaw.exe
del /Q /F %windir%\javaw.exe
```

The fact that it is a disgrace greatly hinders the developer when they have many JVM. Do not rely on the default path, if possible, do not use the system path, because may lie in the system32 java version 1.6 jre installed at 1.7, 1.6 jre and jdk. Create ways to run applications in the batch file and then run it. A similar problem with the environment variables Java: CLASSPATH, QTJAVA, JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, JDK_HOME; Use "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties".

see JRunner.cmd [Eclipse Java Testing Tools - JAVA SE and JSP](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/277125/)

[Not use Java in environment PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/560406/installer-script-for-multiple-software-packages/560424#560424)

save variable environment Java:

```
set | find /I "java" > c:\java-env.txt
```

save variable environment:

```
set > c:\set-env.txt
```

view variable environment Java:

```
set | find /I "java"
```

del variable environment Java:

```
setx CLASSPATH "" 
setx QTJAVA ""
setx JAVA_HOME ""
setx JRE_HOME ""
setx JDK_HOME ""
```

Change `PATH` variable, del Java directory path.

Before running JavaFX set environment variables in `cmd` and run install JavaFX.